# Select 10 percent for each group for the previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I can get the top 10 percent for the previous month using

```
select top 10 percent ID, Ref, Entered_Date, [Type], CREATEDBY, Office, Created_Date, Amt from Tbl 
where DATEPART(m, Entered_Date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) AND DATEPART(yyyy, Entered_Date) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) and 
CreatedBy ='User1')
order by amt DESC
```

I am having to do this many times for each user using a union, how can I do this on one query? When I add the other users CreatedBy in('User1','User2') it doesn't work. I had a look at row over partition but cant figure it out. I'm using SSMS 2017.

Updated with below

```
Select * From(
select ID, Ref, Entered_Date, [Type], CREATEDBY, Office, Created_Date, Amt 
NTILE (10) OVER ( PARTITION BY CREATEDBY ORDER BY Amt desc)  AS PercentageNo
from Tbl 
where DATEPART(m, Entered_Date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) AND DATEPART(yyyy, Entered_Date) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) 
/*Entered_Date between DATEADD(m, -2, getdate())  and DATEADD(m, -1, getdate()) */ )as SubQuery
where PercentageNo=1 order By Amt
```

Comment: Please share some sample data and the expected result

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ntile-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017 NTILE the last months data (use where clause with a BETWEEN rather than converting dates to month and year) into 10 groups partitioned by person and take the 1st ranked one using an outer select/where

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the top 10% for each user, I would recommend using logic such as this:

```
select ID, Ref, Entered_Date, [Type], CREATEDBY, Office, Created_Date, Amt
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user order by amt desc) as seqnum,
             count(*) over (partition by user) as cnt
      from Tbl t
      where Entered_Date >= dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), convert(date, getdate()))) and
            Entered_Date < dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), convert(date, getdate()))
      ) t
where seqnum <= cnt / 10;
order by user, amt desc;
```

Note the change to the date arithmetic.  The functions are all applied only on `getdate()`. This allows indexes to be used to winnow down the data.

The key for solving your problem is using window functions with the `partition by user` construct to do separate counts and enumerations for each user.

Comment: I am getting a few errors with this? t.* , should this be tbl.* or should tbl as t? also saying there is nothing called cnt? thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use `GROUP BY` for select percentage of each user as this:

```
select      top 10 percent ID, Ref, Entered_Date, [Type], CREATEDBY, Office, Created_Date, Amt 
FROM Tbl 
where       DATEPART(m, Entered_Date) = DATEPART(m, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) 
            AND DATEPART(yyyy, Entered_Date) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) 
            AND CreatedBy IN ('User1','User2')
GROUP BY    ID, Ref, Entered_Date, [Type], CREATEDBY, Office, Created_Date, Amt
order by    amt DESC
```

Comment: I have already tried this and does not work as it wont split by user, Using my updated query taken from Caius Jard comment seems to work although I don't fully understand his between dates part. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use row_number() for this reason

Answer (score 0):

This I now woking as expected thanks to Gordon Linoff Re Dates and  Caius Jard for pointing me in to Ntile

```
Select * From(
select ID, Ref, Entered_Date, [Type], CREATEDBY, Office, Created_Date, Amt 
NTILE (10) OVER ( PARTITION BY CREATEDBY ORDER BY Amt desc)  AS PercentageNo
from Tbl 
where Entered_Date >= dateadd(month, -1, dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), convert(date, getdate()))) and Entered_Date < dateadd(day, 1 - day(getdate()), convert(date, getdate())) as SubQuery where PercentageNo=1 order By Amt
```